# RegEX to replace "TOP ZZZZ" in SQL Server query string

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, vb.net, sql-server-2012

I am in need of some help with figuring out how to go about using a **REGEX** to determine what number is *after* the **TOP** in a `SELECT` query string.

Example(s):

```
SELECT top 1000 First_name, Last_name FROM PERS_DAT
SELECT top 50 First_name, Middle_name, Last_Name FROM PERS_DAT
SELECT top 105 Last_name FROM PERS_DAT
```

From the example query strings above, I would like it to output as follows:

```
1000
50
105
```

How would the **REGEX** be in order to find that information out and replace it with my own value?

Comment: are these selects stored as rows in some table..if yes then you can do substr instead of regex.

Comment: `String.Split(New Char() {" "c})[2]` or `Regex.Split(s, "\W+")[2]`

Comment: @RobertHarvey, surely you mean `(2)`, not `[2]` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how flexible the pattern needs to be (how many different kinds of variations in the input that it needs to support), but something like this would be a good start for a regex pattern:

```
(?<=^\s*SELECT\s+TOP\s+)\d+
```

You need to specify that the pattern matching is case-insensitive so that it will match any of the following:

```
SELECT TOP 50
SELECT top 50
select top 50
... etc.
```

Also, if the input string will contain multiple SQL statements, you'll need to specify the multi-line option so that the `^` matches the beginning of each line rather than the beginning of the string.

Here's a complete example:

```
Dim input As String = _
    "SELECT top 1000 First_name, Last_name FROM PERS_DAT" & Environment.NewLine & 
    "SELECT top 50 First_name, Middle_name, Last_Name FROM PERS_DAT" & Environment.NewLine & 
    "SELECT top 105 Last_name FROM PERS_DAT"
Dim pattern As String = "(?<=^\s*SELECT\s+TOP\s+)\d+"
For Each m As Match In RegEx.Matches(input, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase Or RegexOptions. Multiline)
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value)
Next
```

The regex pattern uses a look-behind (i.e. `(?<=)`) statement to specify text that must proceed any valid match.  The only part of the input string that is captured as the value of the match is the `\d+` part (i.e. the number).  Everything else is just saying that the number must be preceded by the beginning of a new line followed by the words "select" and "top" separated by any number of white-space characters.

**Update 1**

Based on your comments below, here is an example of how you can use `Regex.Replace` to replace the number with a different value:

```
Dim input As String = "SELECT top 1000 First_name, Last_name FROM PERS_DAT" 
Dim pattern As String = "(?<=^\s*SELECT\s+TOP\s+)\d+"
Dim output As String = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, Function(x) (Integer.Parse(x.Value) * 10).ToString(), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

In the above example, I am passing a lambda expression for the `MatchEvaluator` parameter.  The lambda converts the matched number to an `Integer`, multiplies it by `10`, and then converts the result to a string and returns that as the replacement value.  So, by providing that lambda expression, it will cause it to replace `SELECT top 1000` with `SELECT top 10000`.

**Update 2**

As a more complex example, if you created a method like this:

```
Private Function CapAt350(m As Match) As String
    If Integer.Parse(m.Value) < 350 Then
        Return m.Value
    Else
        Return "350"
    End If
End Function
```

Then you could use it as your match evaluator like this:

```
Dim input As String = "SELECT top 1000 First_name, Last_name FROM PERS_DAT"
Dim pattern As String = "(?<=^\s*SELECT\s+TOP\s+)\d+"
Dim output As String = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, AddressOf CapAt350, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

Comment: Sorry to confuse. I will only have 1 SQL SELECT statement at a given time. I only added the 3 in my OP to demonstrate 3 times what I would be getting back.

Comment: After finding the number i am looking for **(if m.value > 350)** then I would need to change that higher value to **350**. How would you do that within your **for each** section?

Comment: Each match provides properties that describe the location and length of the match in the original string, however, the easiest thing would be to use `Regex.Replace` rather than looping through the matches.  You can provide the `Replace` method with a custom `MatchEvaluator` method which can return the appropriate replacement value for each input value.

Comment: Could you show that in code in your post by chance?

Comment: I've updated my answer to show an example of that (and also to remove the multi-line option)

Comment: Would that work if I just want to change the number (if its larger than 350) to just 350?

Comment: That did it. Thanks for the help, Steven!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly.

```
 Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
```

code:

```
   Dim qry As String
   qry = "SELECT top 1000 First_name, Last_name FROM PERS_DAT"
   qry = qry.Replace(Integer.Parse(Regex.Replace(qry, "[^\d]", "")), "10") 
   /*'here 10 is a custom value,If you want replace 1000 with 10
   /*'output : SELECT top 10 First_name, Last_name FROM PERS_DAT
```

If you want then create a function like below

```
Function Tune_Query_String(ByVal qry As String, ByVal myval As String)
        Tune_Query_String = qry.Replace(Integer.Parse(Regex.Replace(qry, "[^\d]", "")), myval)
        Return Tune_Query_String
End Function
```

usage:

```
Dim qry As String
qry  = "SELECT top 50 First_name, Middle_name, Last_Name FROM PERS_DAT"
qry = Tune_Query_String(qry,"5")
/*'output:SELECT top 5 First_name, Middle_name, Last_Name FROM PERS_DAT,replaced 50 with 5
```

Comment: I tested it and working for me, Did you tried it  then what's output you got??

Answer (score 0):

If your data is stored in column of a table you can do below with out regular expression:-

```
select substring(firstpart,1,charindex(' ',firstpart,1))
from (select 
substring(quotationId,12,datalength(quotationId)) as firstpart           
              from quotation)x;
```

Sql filldle :- 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/411ee8/29